# What is the best way to store a checklist using Realm.io?

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Android Studio to develop an app that has a field in which the user marks which days of the week they are going to use a certain medication.

I had thought of using an Array of booleans to store that information in a format similar to this

```
  {false,true,true,false,true,true,false}
```

Unfortunately, I just found out that Realm doesn't support arrays, additionally I tried using RealmList but it didn't work either. Does anyone know of a good way to store this info on a database other than creating seven booleans in the class?

Comment: what was your problem with `RealmList `?

Comment: It doesn't support primitive types like boolean.

Comment: why not store it as `{false,true,true,false,true,true,false}`? Or more accurately, `[false, true, true, false, true, true, false]` and `List<Boolean> list = gson.fromJson(realmObject.getDays(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Boolean>>() {});`? But if you need to query per day, you're best off with 7 booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Realm is an object oriented database, which means it stores objects itself. So the best way to approach it is to create a class that extends `RealmObject` with seven boolean properties (each of each day of the week) and maybe the week number in the year or the initial date for the monday, up to you.

Then you can save directly that object by creating a managed Realm instance and store it according to the documentation. You can check how to store a realm instance into the database [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#writes)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to execute queries like "medications that must be taken on wednesdays", then you could store it as a String field

```
[true, false, false, true, true, true, false]
```

And obtain them as `List<Boolean>` using a JSON parser, like [here](https://hackernoon.com/realmlist-realmstring-is-an-anti-pattern-bfc10efb7ca5).

---

If you **do** need to make that query, then you should just create 7 boolean fields.

Comment: I might need to execute queries on it in the future. I guess I'll try and make the boolean solution after all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for storing objects having one `@PrimaryKey` that relates to the day of the week (values 0 - 6 meaning Monday - Sunday) and your boolean field:

```
class Day extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    int dayOfWeek; // could be String as well
    boolean takeMedication;
}
```

You can then query for all the objects and sort by `dayOfWeek` using `findAllSorted()`:

```
realm.where(Day.class).findAllSorted("dayOfWeek");
```

or just query for a certain day:

```
realm.where(Day.class).equalTo("dayOfWeek", 0).findFirst();
```

Pros:

- the `@PrimaryKey` annotation will ensure that you have exactly one instance of `Day` in realm for one `dayOfWeek` value
- Querying makes sense
- No need to do any additional serialization / deserialization from string representing the array or something similar
- Easily extendable to store more day of week specific data - just add more fields to `Day` class.

You can also use [initial data](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#initialData-io.realm.Realm.Transaction-) to ensure you have all 7 days of week stored in the DB by first app launch.

Comment: Can I include that inside another RealmObject class?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely possible, of course then you'd have to consider whether the primary key constraint suits your data model, since having a realm object as a field of another implies unidirectional linking